# Expo emulator does not start

Tags: react-native, expo, vue-native

Im using vue-native a wrapper of react-native. Suddenly, the vue-native project on the emulator stopped running.

When I start the emulator, I get an error

> This version of the app is out of date. Uninstall the app and run
>   again to upgrade.

I tried to remove the expo-cli with

```
npm uninstall expo-cli
```

and installed it again:

```
npm install -g expo-cli
```

I have also deleted my node-modules and done

```
npm install
```

But still Im getting the same error and the vue-native app wont compile.

Any help is very much apreciated

Comment: How did you start your project? vue-native init <projectname> or vue-native init <projectname> --no-crna?

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty common issue with `react-native`. This might help:

After running `npm run ios`, go to the simulator's home page 
 by typing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and delete the Expo app. Run `npm run ios` afterwards which will reinstall the expo app.

Or check out the original answer [here](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/113#issuecomment-289325092).